# Reading files with JFileChooser

Tags: java, file, jfilechooser

I always get a NullPointerException with this code

```
open.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        modify = true;
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        BufferedReader reader;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while(line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            text.setText(sb.toString());
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

NullPointerException on the line `reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));`

How can I reorganize my code?

Comment: Why ask your question 3 times , lol

Comment: Maybe you should actually [show the dialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showOpenDialog%28java.awt.Component%29) first, so the user can pick the file first :-)

Comment: Site asked me to put more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't actually choose the file. Therefore is the chooser returning null when quering it for that selected file name.

You should call `chooser.showOpenDialog()` or `chooser.showSaveDialog()` after creating its instance.

[See how to here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)